# Error Saying "Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert into table which is my 3rd table of many to many relation called 'license'.
I have written insert statement into stored procedure.

I want to insert primary key of customer and product table whose id's are foreign key to third table license i have written insert statement as following:

```
insert into customer`.`tbl_license`(LicenseKey,Quantity,CustomerId,ProductId,Discount) 
                    values((select UUID()),quantity,
(select AutoID from customer.tbl_customer where 
CustomerName=customername),
(select AutoID from customer.tbl_product where 
ProductName=productname),discount);
```

Is this insert statement correct? 
I have written query within insert statement

Comment: select AutoID from customer.tbl_customer where 
CustomerName=customername will return every autoid hence the error. It would be useful if you included the stored procedure perhaps one of the customername's is supposed to come from the procedure. Note- don't give declared variables or parameters the same name as column names.

Comment: where does `quantity` and `discount` on values come from? show the stored procedure.